# I can't get any of the screen recorders to work properly, 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, capture

So is there anyway I can salvage this?

I have tried many screen recorders and none of them work properly on my 22.04 LTS system. Initially I went heavily off from [this Ubuntu guide...](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/record-desktop-with-sound-ubuntu-2204/)

Typically I'm getting a black screen on Wayland. Only the built-in screen recorder works in Wayland but even then the video comes out all choppy and jittery. On Wayland I just get the black screen with all the other screen recorders.

When I switch to X11, when I use the screen recorder Simple Screen Recorder, the video comes out all choppy and jittery. On OBS and Kazam it's funny because it will only record the upper left portion of the screen, so even though it's set to record the whole screen, it will only record the upper left portion of the screen. And yes I've tried Vokoscreen.

I note as well that the built in screen recorder on 22.04 doesn't record sound which is a shame. I hope they fix that for 24.04 LTS.

My PC specs are:

- AMD FX 4300 quad core CPU (which was released in 2012)
- AMD Radeon RX 550 4GB GDDR5
- 16GB DDR3 ram
- Asus M5A78L-M/USB3 motherboard

Am I having these issues just because my hardware is ancient? I have checked in "Software & Updates" it says: "no additional drivers available"

**Some requested information:**

When I enter in command `lspci -vv | grep driver | grep "radeon\|amdgpu"`

It just says `Kernel driver in use: amdgpu`

When I enter command `lspci -vv` I get the following output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RS780 Host Bridge
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    NUMA node: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 24
    NUMA node: 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000c000-0000cfff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: fe900000-fe9fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000cfe00000-00000000dfffffff [size=258M]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity+ SERR+ NoISA- VGA+ VGA16+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 25
    NUMA node: 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: fea00000-feafffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity+ SERR+ NoISA+ VGA- VGA16- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 26
    NUMA node: 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: feb00000-febfffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity+ SERR+ NoISA+ VGA- VGA16- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 27
    NUMA node: 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fdf00000-00000000fdffffff [size=1M]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity+ SERR+ NoISA+ VGA- VGA16- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M4A785TD Motherboard
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 22
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: I/O ports at b000 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at a000 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 9000 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at 8000 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 7000 [size=16]
    Region 5: Memory at fe8ffc00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe8fe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe8fd000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe8ff800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe8fc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe8fb000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 19
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe8ff400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M4A785TD Motherboard
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    NUMA node: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco

00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (prog-if 8a [ISA Compatibility mode controller, supports both channels switched to PCI native mode, supports bus mastering])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at 000001f0 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=8]
    Region 1: Memory at 000003f0 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [virtual]
    Region 2: Memory at 00000170 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=8]
    Region 3: Memory at 00000370 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [virtual]
    Region 4: I/O ports at ff00 [virtual] [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pata_atiixp
    Kernel modules: pata_atiixp, pata_acpi

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. M4A785TD Motherboard
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=slow >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe8f4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle+ MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    NUMA node: 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64
    NUMA node: 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=64
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity+ SERR+ NoISA+ VGA- VGA16- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-

00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 18
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe8fa000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    NUMA node: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    NUMA node: 0

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    NUMA node: 0

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    NUMA node: 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    NUMA node: 0
    Kernel driver in use: fam15h_power
    Kernel modules: fam15h_power

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    NUMA node: 0

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X] (rev c7) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lexa PRO [Radeon 540/540X/550/550X / RX 540X/550/550X]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 34
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 2: Memory at cfe00000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
    Region 5: Memory at fe9c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 35
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe99c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: I/O ports at d800 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at feafc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
    Kernel modules: rtl8192ce

03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. ASM1042A USB 3.0 Host Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: Memory at febf0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    NUMA node: 0
    Region 0: I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at fdfff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at fdff8000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: Let's see, are you saying all the screen recorders are broken on 22.04?

Comment: You should try OBS

Comment: As you seem to have figured out that Wayland is the root of the problem -> run Ubuntu in Xorg session. Can be selected at the login screen.

Comment: @RA OBS doesn't work.

Comment: @user535733 Sorry didn't mean to offend anyone. I've edited my post though, can you help me out? Is there anyway I can fix this?